# track points using kalman filter in opencv c

Tags: c++, opencv

How to draw random points using kalman filter algorithm with opencv c++ code. I have tried with mouse function now instead of mouse function i want random points to be generated and the kalman filter to track all the random points. Here is the mouse function:
struct mouse_info_struct { int x,y; };
struct mouse_info_struct mouse_info = {-1,-1}, last_mouse;

```
  vector<Point> mousev,kalmanv;

  void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) 

  {
    last_mouse = mouse_info;
    mouse_info.x = x;
    mouse_info.y = y;
  }
```

Comment: "Draw points", "track points", "filter points". Make up your mind: what do you want to do?

Comment: can you explain, what kalman-filtering *random* points should result in ? whatever the location of the points is, you still need some kind of *sequence*

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `x` and `y` coordinates of your mouse points by the result of a call to `cv::RNG::uniform()` or `cv::RNG::gaussian()`, depending on what kind of random distribution you want. See the doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rng#RNG).